# In Excel, is there a way to combine specific columns from different worksheets into one worksheet by appending them to the end of the previous one?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

My office has about 8 worksheets that track dates following the process of their specific projects.  There are 6 dates of interest that are common across all of these worksheets, but since every process is different, every sheet is different.  We want to set up a master workbook that retrieves these 6 dates from each spreadsheet so that we can monitor them across the office, automate calculations, etc.

So my essential dilemma is that in worksheet 1, I want all the data in columns A, B, and C.  Then in worksheet 2 I want columns B, D, and F, and in worksheet 3 I want columns K, L, and M, etc., and I'd like to line them up and append them.  So my resulting spreadsheet would look like:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 1B | 1C |
| 2B | 2D | 2F |
| 3K | 3L | 3M |

This doesn't seem like it should be too difficult of a task, but I can't seem to find a solution. I've been trying to investigate the Append feature of PowerQuery, but I can only seem to pull each entire spreadsheet, and they aren't appended into the same columns.  For example, the first spreadsheet would fill in columns A through N and then the second spreadsheet would be pulled in and appended in columns O through AC, etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey Jessica, are these individual dates within single cells or are there multiple/many rows of data?

Answer (score 0):

The Append feature of Power Query is definitely the best tool for this task.  I would start by building a query for each of the 8 worksheets, shaping them into a consistent format. The column names need to be exactly the same in each, and any unwanted output columns need to be removed.  Append will align the column values based on their column names.

Then I prefer to build the Append steps in the final query one at a time.  That way you can step through the Append steps to check the results - in particular if any extra columns were added.

Comment: HI Mike, thanks for the suggestion!  Is there a tutorial on PowerQuery you might recommend?  I'm having a lot of trouble navigating the interface.

Comment: Try these: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-query-101-008b3f46-5b14-4f8b-9a07-d3da689091b5 https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-power-query-course